# Spline regression with variable variance of residuals

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, splines, prediction-interval

I am running a **natural spline regression** x vs y, like in figure (there are also some dummy variables but it doesn't matter here).

It happens that I have a lot of **heteroskedasticity**, i.e. mutable variance of residuals: indeed, just by looking at the image, it seems clear that the variance grows with x.

How can I take that into account? **How can I have prediction intervals** (shown in red in picture) **with variable size with changing x**?
If you can point me to a R library I appreciate.
Thanks
Marco

[image]

Comment: If you can tell us some context,maybe we can help.  Just a plot without any modeling context is not much.